# Is there a way to switch an Actions on Google project to use smart home actions instead of dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-smart-home

I have Actions on Google project which originally used smart home actions.

I then imported a DialogFlow project (from a zip file exported from another project), but now I wish to revert back to smart home actions.
Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't possible to switch

Comment: @NickFelker Seems your comment is the answer (unfortunately).  Add it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck with the same problem. So I decided to mail Support for Action on Google on the same.

Here is the response I received :

> Hi, Thanks for your interest in Actions on Google,
>
> Unfortunately is not possible to convert projects to different
>   frameworks. If you want to create a Smart Home Action you have to
>   create a new project, select Smart Home and then follow the
>   instructions in this guide